# JSX: .map is not a function

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, jsx

I understand the source of the problem, but I'm just a bit stuck on how to resolve it.

I'm doing something like `items.map(item, index)`, but in the browser console I get an entire object. This object has another object within it called `data`, and that's where I'm trying to apply the `map` function, since I understand it only works on arrays. The object looks like this:

```
{
    "data":[
    {"id":"1","name":"a","description":"aaaaaa"},
    {"id":"2","name":"b","description":"bbbbbb"},
    {"id":"3","name":"c","description":"cccccc"}
    ]
}
```

But when I try to do `items.data.map`, I get the error `property 'data' does not exist on type 'Item[]'`, which is true. It only shows up in the browser console.

What am I missing and is it possible to resolve it without adding a `data` property?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data is an array, so to access its inner content, you have to apply map() in a nested manner:

```
items.map((item) => item.data.map((data) => /* you can access the inner data here */));
```

Answer (score -1):

`items.data.map` doesn't work because the key is `"data"`, not `data`

Your object keys should not be strings:

```
{
    data: [
    {id: 1, name: "a", description: "aaaaaa"},
    {id: 2, name: "b", description: "bbbbbb"},
    {id: 3, name: "c", description: "cccccc"}
    ]
}
```

Then you can do:

```
items.data.map((item, index) => ...
```